# Refresh SlickGrid via call to JsonResult after initial load

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, slickgrid

I have setup a MVC webpage with a SlickGrid and can populate it upon initial page load.  My javascript for loading:

```
    $.getJSON("../Home/GetSlickGridData",
        function(data) {
            dataView.beginUpdate();
            //dataView.setItems(data);     
            dataView.setItems(data, "OrderID");
            dataView.setFilterArgs({
                searchString: searchString,
                searchShipmentID: searchShipmentID,
                searchDestination: searchDestination,
                searchCarrier: searchCarrier
            });
            dataView.setFilter(myFilter);
            dataView.endUpdate();
        });
```

This calls a controller action:

```
public JsonResult GetSlickGridData()
        {
```

The issue now is that I'm unsure of how to refresh the grid when a search criteria is added to the cshtml page's search form:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("GetSlickGridData", "Home"))
{
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Shipper</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="myText" id="txtShipper" /></td>
            <td><input type="submit" value="Filter" onclick="GetData"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
}
```

Can I use the loading for initial page load and for a search?

**UPDATE:**

Based on @Steve T's answer:

The search:

```
> <input type="text" name="myText" id="txtShipper" />
>     <input type="button" value="Filter" onclick="GetData()">
```

The jquery:

```
 function GetData() {

        Slick.GlobalEditorLock.cancelCurrentEdit();
        grid.invalidateAllRows();


        var searchText = $("#txtShipper").val();
        $.getJSON("../Home/GetSlickGridData?search=" + searchText,
            function (data) {
```

The controller:

```
  public JsonResult GetSlickGridData(string search)
```

And the map route (to ensure the controller works):

```
 routes.MapRoute("search", "Home/GetSlickGridData/{search}",
                new {Controller = "Home", Action = "GetSlickGridData"});
```

Comment: A helpful post for filtering: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/536283/jquery-getjson-not-passing-any-values-to-controller

Comment: Just checking you are using the 6pac repo (https://github.com/6pac/SlickGrid) and you have seen the AJAX example (http://6pac.github.io/SlickGrid/examples/example6-ajax-loading.html) for which the remote AJAX source seems to have stopped working, but still has useful code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of submitting the form and reloading the whole page you can change the filter button to `type="button"` and then use the `GetData()` function (not sure if you have this already implemented) to repeat the initial `$.getJSON` call with the value of text field `txtShipper` as a parameter